# close! a subscription channel without unsub

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

What are the effects of using `close!` on a subscription channel without first using `unsub`?
Will this have the effect of an implicit `unsub` + a `close!` or will there be any unwanted sideeffects doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pub` and `sub` are implemented in terms of `mult`:

- each topic of a publication channel corresponds to a mult created when the first subscription for that topic is registered,
- each `sub` call results in an under-the-hood call to `tap` on the mult corresponding to the relevant topic.

Mults are internally set up to remove taps that end up putting to a closed channel (this is documented in the docstring of `mult`). In the context of subscriptions, that means that if a subscription channel is closed, its tap will be removed from its mult the first time a message for that topic is published to the publication channel, or in other words, `close!` does cause an implicit `unsub`.

Note that neither `unsub` nor `close!` cause the topic itself (and the corresponding mult) to be removed from the publication's register. If you want that to happen, you can use `unsub-all`.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to determine the answer from the docs, so I made a small async experiment to determine whether `close!` without `unsub` is safe.

```
(ns pubsub.experiment
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as >]))

(def publisher (>/chan))

(def p (>/pub publisher (constantly nil)))

(def answers (>/chan))

(defn consume
  [label count]
  (let [s (>/sub p nil (>/chan))]
    (>/go-loop [i 0]
      (if (> i count)
        (>/close! s)
        (do
          (>/>! answers [label (>/<! s)])
          (recur (inc i)))))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "running pubsub experiment")
  (consume :a 1)
  (consume :b 2)
  (consume :c 3)
  (consume :d 4)
  (consume :e 5)
  (>/go-loop []
    (println "result: " (>/<! answers))
    (recur))
  (>/<!! (>/onto-chan publisher (range 10)))
  (System/exit 0))
```

and then running it (bench.jar is an uberjar containing clojure plus core.async and a couple of other libs).

```
$ java -cp ~/bin/bench.jar:. clojure.main -m pubsub.experiment
running pubsub experiment
result:  [:a 0]
result:  [:b 0]
result:  [:c 0]
result:  [:d 0]
result:  [:e 0]
result:  [:a 1]
result:  [:b 1]
result:  [:c 1]
result:  [:d 1]
result:  [:e 1]
result:  [:b 2]
result:  [:c 2]
result:  [:d 2]
result:  [:e 2]
result:  [:c 3]
result:  [:d 3]
result:  [:e 3]
result:  [:d 4]
result:  [:e 4]
result:  [:e 5]
$
```

As we can see, the `close!` calls don't interfere with any of the other subscribed channels, and each channel sees all the results we expect before closing.